# Why LiveData not updating? (Android, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

How to expose MutableLiveData as LiveData?.

## Code below not working.

**SimpleMixerFragment.kt**

```
private lateinit var binding: MixerSimpleFragmentBinding
private lateinit var viewModel: SimpleMixerViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Inflate view and obtain an instance of the binding class
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.mixer_simple_fragment,
        container,
        false
    )

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SimpleMixerViewModel::class.java)

    binding.simpleMixerViewModel = viewModel

    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

    return binding.root
}
```

**SimpleMixerViewModel.kt**

```
class SimpleMixerViewModel : ViewModel() {

   private val _etDate = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val etDate: LiveData<String>
       get() = _etDate
}
```

**mixer_simple_fragment.kt**

```
<variable name="simpleMixerViewModel" type="....SimpleMixerViewModel" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/etDate"                
                                android:text="@{simpleMixerViewModel.etDate}"/>
```

## This works instead.

**SimpleMixerViewModel.kt**

```
class SimpleMixerViewModel : ViewModel() {

   val etDate = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

**mixer_simple_fragment.xml**

```
<variable name="simpleMixerViewModel" type="....SimpleMixerViewModel" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/etDate"                
                                android:text="@={simpleMixerViewModel.etDate}"/>
```

Comment: Second one works because of two way binding. Please read what is difference between one way and two way binding. From here - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi while theory is similar, that question is for `angularjs` and not `android`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@{}` registers a one-way binding, meaning if you modify `MutableLiveData` from code, then it would propagate the changes to the `EditText`.

`@={}` registers a two-way binding, meaning if you modify either the `MutableLiveData` OR the `android:text` property, then it will update `MutableLiveData -> android:text` OR `android:text -> MutableLiveData` (whichever was modified).

To use two-way binding, you must expose the mutable version of LiveData so that the binding can write the new value of the EditText into the MutableLiveData.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
Is it good practice to expose the MutableLiveData?

Comment: Why does it work? https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/master/GuessTheWordDataBinding/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/guesstheword/screens/game/GameViewModel.kt

Comment: If you are using databinding and two-way binding then it is unavoidable to expose MutableLiveData in this case